# Is It possible to mute all participants audio and video in mediasoup in flutter?

Tags: flutter, video, mute, video-conferencing, mediasoup

I am developing a video-conferencing application in flutter using mediasoup WebRTC. I can implement producer and consumer mute and unmute audio/video by themself. I would like to implement mute all participants through a host. So Please provide an answer if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mute all using below properties

```
mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = !(mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled);
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer if its useful for you then

Comment: I have added this line in the project, but It is not working.